# Find a match in a field and print next n fields

Tags: bash, awk, grep, match

BASH noob here.
I have a tab separated file structured like this:

```
ABC DEF x 123 456

GHI x 678 910
```

I need to match "x" and print x plus the following two fields:

```
x 123 456

x 678 910
```

I've tried a few things but the issue that throws me off is that "x" is not always in the same field. Can please somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in bash, then bash provides *parameter expansions* with substring removal that are built-in. They (along with many more) are:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

So in your case you want to trim the longest path from the front up to `x` as the pattern, e.g.

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    echo "x${line##*x}"
done
```

Where you read each line and then trim from the front until `'x'` is found (you remove the `'x'` as well), so you simply output `"x....."` where `"....."` is the rest of the line (restoring the `'x'`)

(for large data sets, you would want to use `awk` or `sed` for efficiency reasons)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your sample data in a *heredoc*, you could do:

```
$ while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
>     echo "x${line##*x}"
> done << 'eof'
> ABC DEF x 123 456
> GHI x 678 910
> eof
x 123 456
x 678 910
```

You can just select-copy/middle-mouse-paste the following in your xterm to test:

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    echo "x${line##*x}"
done << 'eof'
ABC DEF x 123 456
GHI x 678 910
eof
```

**Using `grep -o` For Simplicity**

You other option, is to use `grep -o` where the `-o` option returns the part of the line only-matching the expression you provide, so

```
grep -o 'x.*$' file
```

Is another simple option, e.g.

```
$ grep -o 'x.*$' << 'eof'
> ABC DEF x 123 456
> GHI x 678 910
> eof
x 123 456
x 678 910
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to match only tab separated field `x`:

```
pcregrep -o '(^|\t)\Kx(\t|$).*' file
```

```
awk 'n=match($0,/(^|\t)x(\t|$)/) {$0=substr($0,n); sub(/^\t/,""); print}' file
```

To print only the two following fields:

```
pcregrep -o '(^|\t)\Kx(\t[^\t]*){2}' file
```

```
awk 'n=match($0,/(^|\t)x\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*/) {$0=substr($0,n,RLENGTH); sub(/^\t/,""); print}' file
```

Comment: Nice use of pcregrep, that's great solutions thanks for sharing, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/[[:space:]]+x[[:space:]]+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[0-9]+$/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

OR to match more than 1 set of digits after `x` with spaces try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/[[:space:]]+x[[:space:]]+([0-9]+[[:space:]]+){1,}[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[[:space:]]+x[[:space:]]+[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[0-9]+$/){  ##Using match function to match regex here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Creating val which has sub string of matched regex(previous step) length.
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",val)      ##Substituting initial space with NULL in val here.
  print val                        ##Printing val here.
}
' Input_file                       ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hehe..... I thought about `awk` for this one... But I had to leave something for you `:)`

Comment: Only other one I could think of was looping `i<=NF` and check if `$i == "x"` and then outputting from there to the end -- but that was messy...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yeah why because it will not check the digits thing, you are right here.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to match `x` and print `x` plus the following two fields:

Using `awk` without any regex:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == "x") break; 
print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}' file
```

```
x   123 456
x   678 910
```

Or, using `gnu sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/(^|.*\t)(x(\t[^\t]+){2}).*/\2/' file
```

```
x   123 456
x   678 910
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove everything before the "x", you can run a `sed` command like this:

```sh
sed 's/^.*x/x/g' file.txt
```

It finds all occurrences of the pattern `^.*x` and replace it with `x`.

Breakdown of `^.*x`:
`^` means beginning of a line 
`.*` a wild card pattern that can be more than one character 
`x` the character "x"

Hence it replaces everything before and including "x" that are on the same line with the new pattern, just "x".

For more info on sed's find and replace command, see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/.

Comment: `sed` is a great choice. The `g` (global) option to `s` isn't really necessary in this case as the regex match will be "greedy" matching from the beginning to the last `'x'`.